# asp.net Web Api routing not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

Here is my routing configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And, here is my controller:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
    public object GetProducts()
    {
       // return all products...
    }

    [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
    public object Product(string name)
    {
       // return the Product with the given name...
    }
}
```

When I try `api/Products/GetProducts/`, it works. `api/Products/Product?name=test` also works, but `api/Products/Product/test` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Here's what I get when I try `api/Products/Product/test`:

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:42676/api/Products/Product/test'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Products' that matches the request."
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because of your routing settings and its default values. You have two choices.

1) By changing the route settings to match the Product() parameter to match the URI.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}", // removed id and used name
    defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

2) The other and recommended way is to use the correct method signature attribute.

```
public object Product([FromUri(Name = "id")]string name){
       // return the Product with the given name
}
```

This is because the method is expecting a parameter **id** when requesting 
*api/Products/Product/test* rather than looking for a **name** parameter.

Comment: OK, it looks like you need to specify the name, like this: `public object Product([FromUri(Name = "id")]string name)`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommended way!

Comment: worked for me! I wanted a different param in the string, but was defined as "id" in the webapiconfig file and your suggestion fixed it!! thanks much.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your update:

> Please note that **WebApi** works based on reflection this means that your curly braces {vars} must match the same name in your methods.

Therefore to match this `api/Products/Product/test` based on this template  `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` YOur method needs to be declare like this:

```
[ActionName("Product")]
[HttpGet]
public object Product(string id){
   return id;
}
```

Where the parameter `string name` was replaced by `string id`.

Here is my full sample:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("GetProducts")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object GetProducts()
    {
        return "GetProducts";
    }
    [ActionName("Product")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object Product(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I tried using a totally different template:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "test",
                routeTemplate: "v2/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, demo = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But it worked fine on my end. Btw I additional removed `[AcceptVerbs("Get")]` and replaced them with `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @ataravati it works fine on my end. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I changed the parameter name, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is defining id as the parameter yet your method expects a name parameter. I prefer attribute routing if you can, then define /api/products/product/{name} on the Product method.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2