# ASP.NET WebAPI controller not working even though routings are correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

My API controllers are never getting instantiated even though i've made sure several times that my routes should be correct according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760762/asp-net-web-api-routing-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067419/asp-net-web-api-2-route-attribute-not-working) question.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );

     app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
class RaspberryController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Test from Owin")
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see it's extremely simple. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my controller class were implicitly `internal` since I didnt specify otherwise. It must be `public` in order for Owin to find the class by reflection. Thus it had nothing to do with routing...

```
public class RaspberryController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = new StringContent("Test from Owin")
        };
    }
}
```